# HTML Modal not closing when pressing in the gray area

Tags: html

I created 2 buttons on HTML, and by pressing a button, it will open a modal screen. This eaxmple is with 2 buttons, but my aim is that a page could have multiple buttons.
When pressing the **X** it closes the modal screen. 
But, if you press outside the modal area, it should close it as well.
This does not work for both buttons.

Any help would be appreciated, or if you know of a easier/better way to work with modal screens. :-)

{

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn0">Open Modal 0</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal0" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal 0..</p>
  </div>

</div>

<button id="myBtn1">Open Modal 1</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal 1..</p>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal0 = document.getElementById('myModal0');
var modal1 = document.getElementById('myModal1');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn0 = document.getElementById("myBtn0");
var btn1 = document.getElementById("myBtn1");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span0 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
var span1 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn0.onclick = function() {
    modal0.style.display = "block";
}
// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn1.onclick = function() {
    modal1.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span0.onclick = function() {
    modal0.style.display = "none";
}
span1.onclick = function() {
    modal1.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal0) {
        modal0.style.display = "none";
    }
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal1) {
        modal1.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have two `window.onclick = function(event)` Second one overrides first one.

So you really should have only one `window.onclick` handler:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn0">Open Modal 0</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal0" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal 0..</p>
  </div>

</div>

<button id="myBtn1">Open Modal 1</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal 1..</p>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal0 = document.getElementById('myModal0');
var modal1 = document.getElementById('myModal1');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn0 = document.getElementById("myBtn0");
var btn1 = document.getElementById("myBtn1");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span0 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
var span1 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn0.onclick = function() {
    modal0.style.display = "block";
}
// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn1.onclick = function() {
    modal1.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span0.onclick = function() {
    modal0.style.display = "none";
}
span1.onclick = function() {
    modal1.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal0) {
        modal0.style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (event.target == modal1) {
        modal1.style.display = "none";
    }

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```